# gatsby-plugin-transition-link AniLink Cover option not hiding previous page quick enough

Tags: reactjs, transition, gatsby

I'm trying to use gatsby-plugin-transition-link in my gatsby site, in order to implement a page transition. I managed to install the packages fine, and implement AniLink correctly. the transition is almost working perfectly in my sandbox, but I'm getting a funny bug.

I'm trying to implement a cover page transition, whereby a coloured div slides across the page, covering it completely. Continuing to slide across the page until out of view, a new active page is revealed behind it.

The problem is: the initial page remains for a split second, even as the cover slides out of view. It overlaps the newly active page for a split second before vanishing. Why is this happening, and how can I make sure that the previously active page hides itself before the new active page displays?

here is a link to my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/m7z386ll6x
click on 'Go to page 2 transition link' on the index page, to see the bug in action. Once you click on the link, the blue cover slides across the page. As the cover slides out of view, still see all the text content from the index page overlapping the new content of page 2, for a split second.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue today and just found good solution to it. Since there is two divs during transition I just simply added an animation to hide unmounting div when its covered by an image.

Note that animation time should be same as duration + add some extra-delay in animation to avoid blinks

```css
.tl-wrapper--unmount {
  /*
    Just make sure animation time is same that transition duration in <AniLink />
    as well add some delay (e.g. 0.2s as in example) to avoid weird blinking at the end
  */
  animation: 1s ease-out 0.2s normal fadeout;
}
@keyframes fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  49% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kptuv)

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this issue but only when using AniLink with `direction="left"` or `direction="right"`  direction="down" did not show this issue.